# How to change a boolean value in FARM

Tags: pymongo, fastapi, web-farm

I am having an issue creating a router that updates a boolean false value to true in my mongodb. All of this is activated by a button on my front end.

```py
    @router.post("/started", response_description="start fight")
    async def update_started(request: Request, started: bool):
        start = await request.app.mongodb["matches"].update_one({"$set": {"started": True}})
        return start

    
    #@router.put("/update", response_description="start fight")
    #async def update_started(started: bool, request: Request):
     #   if started == False:
       #     started = request.app.database["matches"].update_one(
         #       {"started": False}, {"$set": True}
        #    )
```

I've tried many variations of this and am getting a 500 http error

Comment: This is my frontend call 
        startFight = (e) => {
            let data = {
                started: this.state.started,
            }
            axios.post(ip + 'match/started/')
                .then(response => {
                    window.location.href = ip.replace(":8000", ":3000")
                 
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        }

Comment: What error message do you get in the Python console?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`update_one()` takes two parameters; a filter and an update. You've missed off the filter and passed the update to the filter parameter.

This will be logged as an exception somewhere; you should try and find out where the console output goes otherwise tracking these issues down will be hard.